# Get entered time from RadTimePicker c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, time, get, telerik

I have Telerik RadTimePicker in my aspx page. In code behind, I need to get the time from this RadTimePicker control.

> `<telerik:RadTimePicker ID="radTimeStartTime" runat="server" ZIndex="30001">
>       </telerik:RadTimePicker>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get it with "HH:mm:ss" - hour:minutes:seconds

```
DateTime d = radTimeStartTime.SelectedDate.Value;
string time = d.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a name to your RadTimePicker and then :

```
 DateTime myDate = RadTimePickerName.SelectedDate.Value;
```

And myDate to string :

```
 string myString = myDate .ToShortTimeString().ToString();
```

You can also do it in one line, if you just use the string :

```
string myString = RadTimePickerName.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortTimeString().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 DateTime dt = RadTimePicker1.SelectedDate.Value;  
 string time = dt.ToShortTimeString().ToString();
```